# How to toggle/display content individually in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, toggle, display

my question is how can I toggle/display the "Some text" content on onClick individually?.
I can use different function and state for every div an it is working but I know this is not the correct way to do it .
Can you help me with this guys? Thanks

This is my code

```
function App() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(true);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleShow = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      {loaded && (
        <div className={styles.cards_container}>
          <div className={styles.card_container} onClick={handleShow}>
            <h3>Title</h3>
            {show && (
              <div>
                <p>Some text</p>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className={styles.card_container} onClick={handleShow}>
            <h3>Title</h3>
            {show && (
              <div>
                <p>Some text</p>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className={styles.card_container} onClick={handleShow}>
            <h3>Title</h3>
            {show && (
              <div>
                <p>Some text</p>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom component for your card that handles the state for each card:

```
function Card() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleShow = () => {
      setShow(state => !state);
    };

    return <div className={styles.card_container} onClick={handleShow}>
      <h3>Title</h3>

      {show && (
          <div>
            <p>Some text</p>
          </div>
      )}
    </div>
}
```

And use it in your app:

```
function App() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className={styles.App}>
      {loaded && (
        <div className={styles.cards_container}>
          <Card />
          <Card />
          <Card />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but if i have multiple cards each with different content how i proceed?

Comment: That depends on your content. You can pass children or props into your component:

`function Card({title, content}) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleShow = () => {
      setShow(state => !state);
    };

    return <div className={styles.card_container} onClick={handleShow}>
      <h3>{title}</h3>

      {show && (
          <div>
            <p>{content}</p>
          </div>
      )}
    </div>
}`

and in your app:

`<Card title="My title" content="Some text" />`
`<Card title="Other title" content="Some text" />`